# Solve $y'=xy$, $y(0)=0$ with Picard's method

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

here I have to use Picard's successive approximation method:
we have: $ϕ_0(t)=0$
and $$ϕ_{n+1}(t)=\int_0^t s\cdot ϕ_n(s) ds $$

=> $$ϕ_{1}(t)=\int_0^t s\cdot ϕ_0(s) ds = c $$

$$ϕ_{2}(t)=\int_0^t s\cdot ϕ_1(s) ds = ct^2/2$$

$$ϕ_{3}(t)=\int_0^t s\cdot ϕ_2(s) ds =c*t^4 / 8$$

$$ϕ_{4}(t)=\int_0^t s\cdot ϕ_3(s) ds =c*t^6 / 48$$

.....

My problem is that I can't find a general formula like $$ϕ_{n}(t)=...$$

Comment: Do you realize that all iterates are identically zero?

Comment: So, everything is wrong?

Comment: For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: You are mixing up definite and indefinite integrals. For example $\phi_1(t)  = \int_0^t s \cdot 0 \, ds = 0$ and not some constant $c$.

Comment: So, everything is equal to 0? 0 is the answer?

Comment: Yes. (Not very surprising, since $y(t) = 0$ is a solution to the initial value problem.)

Comment: okay thank you!